# Spinner selection issue

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I want to implement the below:
A spinner which would have a custom layout, its background color would be black and font would be white. But what I want is that when I select any component then my selection background and font color should reverted back to its defaults (in terms of color).

Comment: Did you try to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rao use custom Spinner and for colour state change use [Color State list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Comment: +1 Rao, without giving more detail with code you have tried , this is exact answer for you.